# wp_update_post meta causing 500 error

Tags: wp-update-post

I'm troubleshooting a client site on GoDaddy and I have this strange issue that when I try and run update_post_meta the server throws a 500 error accompanied by this error message: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Redis_Object_Cache::incr2()

If I change the meta key the 500 error stops.

I found a solution and will add an answer but I'm still not sure why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution by following the advice in this article (https://www.godaddy.com/community/Building-and-Managing-a-Website/fatal-error/td-p/31814):

> Open your hosting account, go to File manager and access this folder: wp-content
>   Rename this file object-cache.php to object-cache-OLD.php

As a developer I don't know how to prevent this for future clients without a greater understanding. Comments and new answers welcome.

Comment: This sounds like an issue limited to managed GoDaddy hosting, so it would be best to [inquire with them](https://www.godaddy.com/community/Managed-WordPress-Hosting/bd-p/ManagedWordPressHosting) to find out how the issue can be proactively stopped.